# Watch for change of the input[type="checkbox"]

Tags: jquery

How can I run a function on checkbox change?

I'm trying to write small checkbox replacing function base on that - but I'm doing something wrong.

Code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checking = function() {
        if ($('.checbox').prop('checked', false) === true) {
            $('.new-checkbox').prop('id', 'unchecked');
        } else {
            $('.new-checkbox').prop('id', 'checked');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.checkbox').wrap('<div class="checkbox-wrapper"></div>');
    $('.checkbox-wrapper').append('<p class="new-checkbox">Blue = Checked, Red = Unchecked</p>');
    $('.checkbox').checking();
    $('.checbox').bind('change', function() {
        $(this).checking();

    });

});
```

PlayGround: [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/yGBAK/)

Comment: Quit tagging your titles please. We already have tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have some typos and errors in your script.

```
if($('.checbox').prop('checked', false) === true)
//         ^                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be

```
if(this.prop('checked'))
```

`if($('.checkbox').prop('checked'))` would work too of course, but why select the element again, if you already made it a plugin and the element is available via `this`?

And

```
$('.checbox').bind('change', function(){
//      ^
```

should be

```
$('.checkbox').bind('change', function(){
//      ^
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/yGBAK/40/

That said, it is better (more logical) to add and remove a class than changing the ID of the element.

Comment: I was just about to look for an errors in the statement! Thanks Felix.

Answer (score 19):

Is this what you want? I am under the impression that you are over-complicating things.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    alert ("The element with id " + this.id + " changed.");
});
```

Comment: `input:checkbox` selector will do just fine

Comment: @jAndy: Copy/paste will do just fine too. :)

Comment: Yes. I've actually tried that one before - but did not work. I know know there an issue with if/else statement not .change(); Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    alert('changed');
})
```

I usedthe class you placed on the checkbox (.checkbox) for this.
It detects a change in the state of the checkbox (this works for other inputs as well)

The example I included alerts 'changed' one the checkbox is clicked or unclicked.

If you want to know if it is checked or not every time then:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('not checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    alert("I'm changed!");
});
```

Or

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('I\'\m --> checked');
    } else {
        alert('I\'\m --> unchecked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the selector uses checbox, should be ".checkbox"

I modified your example so it works: http://jsfiddle.net/yGBAK/41/

I swapped the ids for elements.