# Check if Bootstrap data-style is on or off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this bootstrap checkbox, and I want to pop up an alert dialog whenever it is turned off.

```
<div class="row">
       <link href="css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="javascript/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

       <!-- Status checkbox if ON or OFF -->

       <input type="checkbox" id="status-check" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
</div>
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571948/watch-for-change-of-the-inputtype-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("#status-check").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("off")) {
        alert("off");
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o99p387p/)

Comment: Thank you sir. I have tried your suggestion. Works like a charm! I also understood the flow of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a "change" handler to the checkbox, which will run whenever it changes:

```
$("#status-check").bind("change",function(){
    if(!this.checked){
        alert("not selected")
    }
});
```

Comment: please explain your answer a bit. it really helps the questioner understand your answer

Comment: I had a trouble of understanding at first, but I still tried it. Both answers works smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: This is a mix of old jquery and raw javascript, why do that?